# Heroku give me error Process exited with status 126?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, heroku, deployment

```
2022-07-13T13:43:44.217146+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-07-13T13:43:55.537774+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2022-07-13T13:43:56.401821+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126
2022-07-13T13:43:56.281396+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: No such file or directory
2022-07-13T13:43:56.492509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

and my backend code is=

```
// let Pusher = require('pusher');
require("dotenv").config()
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const http = require("http")
const server = http.createServer(app)
const URL = process.env.MONGO_URL
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hii, Mom")
})
try {
    mongoose.connect(URL, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("not connected")
        }
        else {
            console.log("connected to db")
        }
    })

} catch (err) {
    console.log("connection err")
    console.log(err)
}
server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log({ err })
    }
    else {
        const port = server.address().port;
        console.log("server  is start at port " + port)
    }
})
```

my procfile is = **web: node index.js**
when i open route "/". then it is give me error

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner,
 check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
```

while i have set Mongo_URL on Heroku as env variables.how to resolve this problem.please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your back-end code in a file called `index.js` in the root directory of your project? That's what your `Procfile` says, but the error suggests otherwise.

Comment: yes, my back-end code in index.js which inside root directory. yet it is give this error.